# Flask SqlAlchemy Store multiple values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a class called users. A user can like posts. The like count is registered as a number on the post class. On the user class, the post's id is registered on it so that multiple likes can't be given. However, sql on flask only stores datatypes like integers and strings. How am I supposed to keep track of what posts a user has liked?

I have some code for a user like:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    status = db.Column(db.String(100))
    about = db.Column(db.String(500))
    liked = db.Column(Something that would store integer ids of posts)

    def __init__(self, name, email, password, status):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.status = status
        self.about = "Sample"
        self.liked_posts = []
```

Comment: This sounds like a many-to-many relationship: A given user can like multiple posts, and a given post can be liked by multiple users. That would suggest an association table with two columns – a foreign key to each table – and a primary key over both columns. The PK would prevent dupes, and the "like count" for a given post would be `SELECT COUNT(*) AS likes FROM like_table WHERE post_id = ?`

Comment: To elaborate on @GordThompson comment above; you want another table called LikedPosts that has 2 columns, `user_id` and `post_id`. Every time a user likes a post you add a record to this LikedPosts table with the appropriate user_id and post_id.
In theory you could then extrapolate the number of likes on a given post by running a 'count' query across this LikedPosts table: select count(*) from LikedPosts where post_id = SOME_ID; However is probably more preformant to track post like counts somewhere else like the Post table or in an in another datastore.

Comment: What if I store it as a string? So "1|123123|1627|992" could be a string that I store all ids in separated by |. Would that work or would it go beyond the limits that python can handle?

Comment: You can use the django module with `import django`, which gives you access to databases and a bigger framework